# Where to store VSTS extension custom data produced during CI pipeline

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

Does TFS/VSTS provide some API to store and query some custom data?

I would like to write extension with build task that calculates some code metrics and then visualize the data in dashboard widget. For example, how dependency complexity changes over time in my repository.